# Properties with the same name to serialize

Tags: c#, .net, json.net

I have a group of objects that i want to serialize. 
In a specific class, i have two properties, and i know that always one of them it will be null. So, i want serialize this properties with same name and ignoring the one that is null.
The next code is an example. In this case Data is null and Data1 is not, but in the real case the conditions of the problem will determine which one will be null.

```
public class DataToSerialize 
{     
    [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public TData Data { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Data", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public TData1 Data1 { get; set; }

    public DataToSerialize()
    {
        Data = null;
        Data1 = new TData1();
    }

 }
```

When i try to serialize the object is thrown the next exception:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'A member with the name 'Data' already exists on 'DataToSerialize'. Use the JsonPropertyAttribute to specify another name.'
```

Comment: `[JsonIgnore]`?

Comment: But i want ignore only if it's null. imagine that now Data1 is null and Data is not. I want ignore Data1 and serialize Data with the "Data" name

Comment: You should edit your question to include that. At the moment it sounds like one is always null, and that it can't change between them.

Comment: You mean "properties", not "attributes". Attributes means something else and makes the question *slightly* confusing at first.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I made the corrections. John gave me the answer tha i need. Thanks John.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest option might be to decorate both with a `[JsonIgnore]` attribute, and then have a separate property which supplies the non-null value:

```
public class DataToSerialize 
{     
    [JsonIgnore]
    public TData Data { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public TData1 Data1 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("data")]
    public object SerializableData
    {
        get { return Data1 == null ? (object)Data : Data1; }
    }
 }
```

Or if it's appropriate to your use case, simply use a generic class:

```
public class DataToSerialize<TData>
{     
    public TData Data { get; set; }
}
```